# Получаю от сервера POST / HTTP1.1

Tags: java, android

Когда пытаюсь получить html код страницы. Падает приложение на

java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: POST / HTTP/1.1

После разбора в чем может быть дело обнаружил что ответ от сервера приходит POST / HTTP/1.1 вместо HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

```
    private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con) throws IOException {
    if (con != null) {
        System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        try {
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String input;
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(input);
            }
        } finally {
            con.disconnect();
            if (null != inputStreamReader) {
                inputStreamReader.close();
            }
            if (null != br) {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Складывается ощущение что при получении ответа, он просто создаёт новое подключение. Пробовал и через HttpsURLConnection и через OkHttp. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: А может проблема в сервере?

Comment: проблема в том, что сервер не соответствует спецификации HTTP, т. к. отдает не валидный контент. Простого способа решить эту проблему на клиенте нет, и это однозначно проблема не клиента, а сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Выдержка из [RFC-2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html):

> Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF

Что указывает на то, что сервер просто не соответствует стандарту HTTP. Проблема сервера, не клиента.